# Can not add objects from a different Realm iOS & Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

In my app I am managing multiple realm databases files, that's it, for each logged in user a realm file (.realm) exists.

So when the user login to the app I am doing the following:

```
class func setDefaultsForLocationId(_ userId: String) {
    var config = RealmManager.realmConfiguration()
    // Use the default directory, but replace the filename with the business id
    config.fileURL = config.fileURL!.deletingLastPathComponent()
        .appendingPathComponent("\(userId).realm")
    // Set this as the configuration used for the default Realm
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
}
```

once that done I start to add to realm using:

```
fileprivate func storeTransaction(_ student: Student) -> Bool {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    var retVal = true
    do {
        try realm.write {
            realm.add(student, update: true)
        }
    } catch {
        retVal = false
    }
    return retVal
}
```

that will work fine until the current user logout and a new one logged in it will throw an exception :
Can not add objects from a different Realm.

Note 1: I am using only one realm instance at a time not multiple instances from different .realm files at the same time.

Note 2: I found out that if I am logout and login using the same account; the exception will not appear, only if I use different accounts!

Answer (score 2):

In general, adding objects from a different Realm is considered to be a bug. There is no point in separating files if objects are mixed. Therefore, when switching Realm files you should destroy or reload objects belonging to the previous Realm yourself.

If that is an intentional behavior, there is a way to avoid exceptions by detaching `Student` objects from Realm as follows.

```
fileprivate func storeTransaction(_ student: Student) -> Bool {
    let detachedStudent = Student(value: student)
    ...
        realm.add(detachedStudent)
    ...
```

Comment: In general I am using one realm at a time, I don't handle multiple realm instances from different .realm files at the same time.
I am wondering if there is a way to flush in memory for realm!

Comment: the detached idea doesn't work ! it produces the same exception

Comment: Maybe `Student` has other objects as relations? If so, you should detach relation objects recursively. Anyway, since you don't handle multiple realms simultaneously, you should purge old realm objects when switching realm. So you should re-create realm and re-fetch realm objects after switch realm. Can you please show how to invoke `storeTransaction()` method?

Comment: Yes, it has a property of type List<SomeObject>, how would the detach would be then!
Actually I tried to purge by deleting all the realm objects using realm.deleteAll() but nothing changed.

 the storeTransaction() is invoked from a manager called StudentsManager which create the Student's instance and pass it as a parameter to storeTransaction(_ student: Student)

Comment: @MohamMadSalah No, "purge" doesn't mean delete objects. I meant is references. I must leave references of `Student` objects that comes from the previous Realm. Then it would be passed `storeTransaction()` method. So, you should re-fetch `student` before pass `storeTransaction()` when switching Realm.

Comment: @ kishikawa katsumi is there any way to detect which objects are referenced from the old realm!

Comment: @MohamMadSalah Compare realm like `student.ream != realm`. But is does not resolve the issue essentially. Could you please show me your code in more detail? What is the code where passing `student` object to `storeTransaction()` method? I think that you are misunderstanding how to use Realm.

Comment: Ok here is what I conclude and fixed the problem, Studen class has a function which returns a singleton instance of another realm class. So when I switch to another realm; that singleton instance will still the same.
So what I did is whenever I switch to another realm; I do reset that instance which fixed my problem!